# Differences in Facebook Page talks

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have created a Facebook Page ([this](https://www.facebook.com/2222FacesCom)) and run a short-term (few days) Facebook Pages Ads campaign for it. Once the campaign ended, I visited my own page and saw message below title says `70 likes · 33 talking about this`.

However, when just a few seconds later I opened **exactly the same page** from my tablet (while not being logged in to Facebook), saw in the very same place message saying `70 likes · 70 talking about this`. I immediately asked my wife and friend to do the same (while being logged in with their Facebook accounts) and both of them had seen `70 likes · 70 talking about this` as well.

These values for *me* had changed (to current, I think correct) state today, after 10 hours since above mentioned situation.

What am I missing? Why there are such huge differences and page / value updating lags? And why *the most important person* (from this point of view), that is page admin and the one, who paid for ads is seeing real (correct?) values as the last one, while all others (both logged in and not) see them first?